# Change vertex buffer dynamically in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm developing a cloth simulator in WebGL, got all the physics and the animation ready but I just can't render it. I am used to use glVertex in Opengl, so in every iteration I can change the position of the vertex and it will move, but in WebGL (OpenGL ES) there is not such method.

This is my code:

```
//Initialization:
    puntosBuffer= gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, puntosBuffer);
    telaVertices3=new Array(12);
    telaVertices3=[
    0.0,0.0,0.0,
    2.0,0.0,0.0,
    1.0,1.7,0.0,
    0.0,1.0,0.0
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(telaVertices3), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

//loop:
    posx=posx+0.2;
    telaVertices3[0]=posx;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, puntosBuffer);
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, new Float32Array(telaVertices3));
```

But it always renders at the same points!!!

Comment: Do you really need to change the vertex buffer just to move an object on the scene? Couldn't you just use a translation world matrix and multiply it to your vertices positions on the Vertex Shader?

Comment: The questioner wants to move the points semi-independently of each other - e.g. a flag represented by a grid waving in the wind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use additional calls to `gl.bufferData(...)` instead of `gl.bufferSubData(...)`. I don't know if this matters or not, but I think it's the only thing I'm doing differently from your example.

You can see my current implementation of buffer management at [jax/buffer.js#L48](https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/jax/blob/6a807a9922f084a34c5aa46f716810575075f098/src/jax/webgl/core/buffer.js#L48) and an older version at [webgl/buffer.js#L26](https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/webgl/blob/master/public/javascripts/engine/buffer.js#L26). As you can see, I'm not doing anything special:

```
gl.bindBuffer(self.bufferType, buffer);
gl.bufferData(self.bufferType, instance, self.drawType);
```

You can see the animation in a live demo at [webgldemos/md2](http://webgldemos.thoughtsincomputation.com/engine_tests/md2).

### However

If you're planning to update a lot of vertices at once then this is probably not the best method. Instead, I'd propose sending the relevant data down to the video card and performing animation directly within GLSL, so that you aren't limited by JavaScript slowness and can take advantage of hardware acceleration. In fact, I'm transitioning most of my code to work this way. Two live examples of vertex manipulation on the video card are available at [jax/blobular](http://sinisterchipmunk.github.com/blobular.html) and [jax/meadow](http://sinisterchipmunk.github.com/meadow.html). The source code for those demos is freely available [here](https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/sinisterchipmunk.github.com/tree/a1d33070c7ab28ad4fac1035d1e1478b05aeca0c/src/blob) and [here](https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/sinisterchipmunk.github.com/tree/a1d33070c7ab28ad4fac1035d1e1478b05aeca0c/src/meadow), respectively.

I hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: I just realized I didn't thank you for the answer. It helped a lot, thx ;)

Comment: I've been thinking about what you said about transitioning processing into the GPU, which makes sense, but are you not then limited. For example, instead of simply doing += 0.2, I'm dynamically adjusting data with user interaction. How could this be dealt with?

Comment: Some links are down.